# boost thread lock error

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking

I have this code which is giving the error:

```
 error this boost::lock_error
 error this boost::lock_error
 error this boost::lock_error
 error this boost::lock_error
 error this boost::lock_error
```

Since I don't know where is the error I'll try to copy the code:

Main

```
  boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool>  tuple = dups.back();
  ppa::Node *n = boost::get<0>(tuple);
  cout << "creating other threads" << endl;
  for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
  {
    cout << "making  thread " << i << endl;
    g.create_thread( boost::bind( threaded_function, boost::ref(mf), 
                                    boost::ref(n) ));
  }
```

Threads

```
  void threaded_function(Model_factory &mf, ppa::Node *root)
  {
    try 
    {   
      while(true)
      {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(result_mutex);

        if(wait.empty())
        {
          lock.unlock();
          break;
        }
        else 
        {
          lock.lock();
          if(!running_jobs.empty())
          {
            cout << "vector wait size = " << wait.size()   << "\n";
            cout << "running size   = " << running_jobs.size() << "\n";
            cout << "done size  = " << done.size()   << "\n";
            boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> tuple;
            tuple = running_jobs.back();
            running_jobs.pop_back();
            ...
          }
          ...
        }
        ...
      }
    }
    catch (boost::lock_error& le)
    {
      cout << "error this " << le.what() << endl;
    }
  }
```

The code is used in a alignment program I'm trying to do parallel, it aligns the tuples one by one in different threads, until the waiting list (vector wait) is empty. Thanks.
I have done something I put a `lock.unlock()` before every if and else and its working now, but why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are locking the mutex twice.

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(result_mutex);
```

locks the mutex for you. It will also unlock it when it goes out of scope, so you don't need to unlock it by yourself.

So the following lines are unnecessary:

```
lock.lock();
lock.unlock();
```

Comment: ok, but the func doesn't leave the scope, it stays there, so I added the unlock after every if and else and it's sort of working, side some randoms seg faults

Comment: The unlock is necessary because the break statement will cause the loop to terminate and the lock will go out of scope (automatic unlock). Also the second lock is not necessary, since the lock has already done by the creation of the scoped lock. Maybe you should move the scoped lock somewhere else or control the mutex directly with lock/unlock (without using scoped lock at all)

Comment: Ha I see and how it should go, can you provide some example, thanks.